The URL Changes but page doesn't
I made this project with tauri-svelte.
// src/+page.svelte

<script lang="ts">
</script>

<main id="container">
<a href="/routes">
    <button>2nd Page</button>
  </a>
</main>

// src/routes/+page.svelte

<div>
  <h1>Second Page</h1>
  <a href="/">
    <button>Home</button>
  </a>
</div>

Project Folder Image
When I Click on the 2nd Page button It just changes the URL in the URL bar, but nothing changes.
Tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

You can't have +page.svelte files in the src folder, you can only have these in the src/routes folder (and its sub-folders).

Your src/routes/+page.svelte corresponds to the root of your application ("/").
You then create new routes by making new folders inside src/routes/ and giving them their own +page.svelte.
See routing.

So, I've made +page.svelte in src/routes folder.
And made another file +page.svelte in routes/about/.
But it's still not working
<a href="/about">     <button>About</button>   </a>
